# Do Office 365 monthly subscription (the plans including desktop software) include upgrades to newer Office products e.g. Office 2016

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2013

Is there any documentation around whether a Microsoft Office 365 subscription (the plans including desktop software) includes upgrades to newer Office desktop products? e.g. upgrading from Office 2013 to Office 2016 in the future

I am planning on buying it outright if not.

Comment: Office 365 always provides you the current version.  Even today `Office 365` isn't `Office 2013`.

Comment: @Ramhound I am specifically asking about the desktop version that you can download as part of the the Office 365 subscriptions. NOT the website version of Office. Thanks

Comment: I know what you were talking about.  I use it daily.  My answer is still valid.  You get the current version of the product.

Comment: @Ramhound So when they release Office 2016 you will be able to download the latest version?

Comment: You download the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have an Office 365 Subscription and have used it to install Office 2013 on your PC, then you have Office 2013 on your PC.
Once Office 2016 became available, it was made available for download and install through your Subscription.  The 2013 version you already have installed on your machine does NOT automatically update to Office 2016.

All of this, however, is subject to change.  Office 2016 just came out and Microsoft has been pushing their new software more aggressively than in the past.  Windows 10 is a perfect example of this.

I hope this information helps :)